# I am creating a custome page layout using aura component in salesforce . IDK why this type orf error is coming

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura

```
<aura:component
    implements="Lightning:appHomeTemplate"
    description="Three Column Layout"
    access="global">
    <aura:attribute name="left" type="Aura.component[]" access="global" />
    <aura:attribute name="centre" type="Aura.component[]" access="global" />
    <aura:attribute name="right" type="Aura.component[]" access="global" />

    <div aura:id="container">
        <lightning:layout>
            <lightning:layoutitem aura:id="leftColumn" size="2">
                {!v.left}
            </lightning:layoutitem>
            <lightning:layoutitem aura:id="centreColumn" size="7" class="centre">
                {!v.centre}
            </lightning:layoutitem>
            <lightning:layoutitem aura:id="rightColumn" size="3">
                {!v.right}
            </lightning:layoutitem>
        </lightning:layout>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Aura is case sensitive. The "L" in `lightning` is lowercase.